# block access to page Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, user-permissions

I've created log in page for my website with Zend Framework, It works.
in Page A *(www.example.com/a)* , user must log in to system , and if username and password match , user goes to Page B,C,..*(www.example.com/b)* 
but if anybody insert  a link directly *(www.example.com/b)* ,It can see page B , without any permission, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plugin.

For example, you can try something like this:

In your bootstrap, add this function (to declare the plugin)

```
public function _initPlugins(){
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_PRoutage());
}
```

with this example, in the `application/plugins` folder, create the `PRoutage.php` plugin like this:

```
class Application_Plugin_PRoutage extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {  
        if ( FALSE === Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) 
        {  
            // Redirection to login page
            $request->setControllerName('login')
                     ->setActionName('login')
                     ->setDispatched(true) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Zend, but it can be done simply in Laravel using the filter 'before: auth' in route.

```
Route::get('b', ['before'=>'auth', function() {
    //return your View here
}]);
```

This way before visiting page 'b' directly via URL, the system will check if user is authenticated, if not, it will display error page.

You may refer Zend_Auth API for implementation details in Zend, it will be similar:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html